# Error JsonWebTokenError: jwt malformed keep showing up for authentication

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, react-redux

I am a newbie in MERN stack. I am building a forum and I want only logged in user to like and comment post. But I keep getting jsonwebtokenError: jwt malformed.

please help I don't know what to do again as I am totally confused.
below is the middleware

```js
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";

const auth = async (req, res, next) => {
   try {
        console.log(req.headers)
       const token = req.headers.authorization.split('')[1];
       
       const  isCustomAuth = token.length < 500;
       let decodedData;

       if(token && isCustomAuth) {
        decodedData = jwt.verify(token, "TEST");

        req.userId = decodedData?.id;
       } else {
        decodedData = jwt.decode(token);
        req.userId = decodedData.sub;
        // console.log("hello")
       }

       next();
    }
     
    catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}

export default auth;
```

Below is the code for signin and signup

```js
import bcrypt from "bcryptjs";
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";

import User from "../models/user.js";

export const signin = async (req, res) => {
    const { email, password } = req.body;

    try {
        const existingUser = await User.findOne({ email });
        if(!existingUser) return res.status(404).json({ message : "User doesn't exist"});
        const isCorrectPassword = await bcrypt.compare(password, existingUser.password);
        if(!isCorrectPassword) return res.status(400).json({ message: "Invalid credentials"});

        const token = jwt.sign({ email: existingUser.email, id: existingUser._id}, "TEST", {expiresIn: "1h"});
        res.status(200).json({result: existingUser, token})
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({message: 'Something Went wrong'})
    }
}

export const signup = async (req, res) => {
    const { email, password, confirmPassword, firstName, lastName} = req.body;
    try {
        const existingUser = await User.findOne({ email });
        if(existingUser) return res.status(404).json({ message : "User already exist"});
        if(password !== confirmPassword)  return res.status(404).json({ message : "Password do not match"});

        const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 12);

        const result = await User.create({ email, password: hashedPassword, firstName, lastName});
        const token = jwt.sign({ email: result.email, id: result._id}, "TEST", {expiresIn: "1h"});
        
        res.status(200).json({result, token})

    } catch (error) {
        console.log('error', error)
        res.status(500).json({message: 'Something Went wrong'});
    }
}
```

The error am getting is below

```js
{
  host: 'localhost:5000',
  connection: 'keep-alive',
  'sec-ch-ua': '"Google Chrome";v="105", "Not)A;Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="105"',     
  accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
  authorization: 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJlbWFpbCI6Im9kdW5AZ21haWwuY29tIiwiaWQiOiI2MzFlMzk3NDRhZmQ5YjBjMmZhZjllM2QiLCJpYXQiOjE2NjI5MzEwODUsImV4cCI6MTY2MjkzNDY4NX0.MD6kwkHc7tMo7G_o7N6Do8i3SFGD6mb8JVp3ePSdTMw',
  'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
  'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
  origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
  'sec-fetch-site': 'same-site',
  'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
  'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
  referer: 'http://localhost:3000/',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
  'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9'
}
JsonWebTokenError: jwt malformed
    at Object.module.exports [as verify] (C:\Users\user\Desktop\TemmyProject\Inspiredformen\server\node_modules\jsonwebtoken\verify.js:63:17)
    at auth (file:///C:/Users/user/Desktop/TemmyProject/Inspiredformen/server/middleware/auth.js:12:27)
```

Comment: try `console.log("Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJlbWFpbCI6Im9kdW5AZ21haWwuY29tIiwiaWQiOiI2MzFlMzk3NDRhZmQ5YjBjMmZhZjllM2QiLCJpYXQiOjE2NjI5MzEwODUsImV4cCI6MTY2MjkzNDY4NX0.MD6kwkHc7tMo7G_o7N6Do8i3SFGD6mb8JVp3ePSdTMw".split('')[1])` and the issue will be obvious - `e` is not a valid JWT .... you should split on space ... `.split(' ')`

Comment: Thanks Jaromanda X.  I actually resolved it by adding space between the .split quote  .split( '    ' )

Comment: yes, that's what I said you need to do